# GCR.io race condition?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I've just done the set of commands for a new compute engine VM deploy:

```
docker build . -t $GCR_ADDRESS
docker push $GCR_ADDRESS

gcloud compute instances create $APP_ID --image-project=cos-cloud --image-family=cos-77-lts --machine-type=e2-micro --zone=us-central1-a --metadata=GCR_ADDRESS=$GCR_ADDRESS --metadata-from-file=startup-script=./start.sh --tags=http-server,https-server --scopes=default,bigquery,compute-rw --address=$APP_ID-ip
```

And it failed, because startup-script failed to run this:

```
docker run --rm gcr.io/my-project/my-app:latest
```

With error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for gcr.io/my-project/my-app:latest not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "latest" from request
t "/v2/my-project/my-app/manifests/latest"
```

I've ssh-ed into this instance and ran `docker run --rm gcr.io/my-project/my-app:latest` again. And it worked.

This is extremely disturbing. Does it mean that `docker push` command finished before the gcr.io makes image available?

Comment: have you tried to create the image without the script?

Comment: yes, it worked fine. This happened only once.

Answer (score 0):

For me this work as expected.

```
$ gcloud compute instances create test-so00 --image-project=cos-cloud --image-family=cos-77-lts --machine-type=e2-micro --zone=us-central1-a --metadata=GCR_ADDRESS=gcr.io/xxxxxx-projects-xxxxxx/alpine:latest --metadata-from-file=startup-script=./start.sh --tags=http-server,https-server --scopes=default,bigquery,compute-rw
```

Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxxxxx-projects-xxxxxx/zones/us-central1-a/instances/test-so00].

NAME       ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
test-so00  us-central1-a  e2-micro                   10.xxx.0.31  35.224.xx.xxx  RUNNING

Comment: The command also worked for me:

gcloud compute instances create test-so00 --image-project=cos-cloud --image-family=cos-77-lts --machine-type=e2-micro --zone=us-central1-a --metadata=GCR_ADDRESS=gcr.io/xxxxxx-projects-xxxxxx/alpine:latest --metadata-from-file=startup-script=./start.sh --tags=http-server,https-server --scopes=default,bigquery,compute-rw
Created [https://XXXXXXX/test-so00].

NAME       ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP    EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
test-so00  us-central1-a  e2-micro                   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX RUNNING